# How do I know which Android apps have been started through code

Tags: java, android

I want know started apps recently with low cpu, so I dont want user `activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()` and so on, plz help me

I tried use activityManager, but this method mad cpu surge

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `UsageStatsManager`. This will provide you all the historical usage data.

Comment: this won't add cpu cost?

Comment: Using the `UsageStatsManager` will only be a low-cost way of getting the information without any impact for the app performance.